# How to have Gdx.input.istouched return false when I pressed on a button?

Tags: libgdx

I am new to game programming and even more so to libGDX. I would appreciate it if someone can look at this problem.

simply put, I am now making a flappy bird game. I used Gdx.input.istouched to checked if any point of the screen has just being touched. If so, then the rest of the code calls on bird.jump(). That works well until I added a pause button. Now the bird jumps before the button is able to pause the game. How can I have the game pause and not have the bird jump when I press the pause button?

You can view my code if you want, I am making it open sourced anyhow. This is my [code.](https://github.com/GAO23/Flappy-Trump/blob/master/core/src/com/gao23/trumpbird/States/playState.java)

Comment: You should read the guide to asking questions, particularly on how to provide a How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. You should also include the relevant code in your question.

Comment: Don't use justTouched. Use an InputListener.

Answer (score 1):

Use `InputProcessor` and override `touchDown(..)` method of listener. Moreover you need to mux that listener with your hud stage InputProcessor.

```
InputMultiplexer inputMultiplexer=new InputMultiplexer();
    inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(new InputAdapter() {

        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

            bird.jump();
            return super.touchDown(screenX, screenY, pointer, button);
        }
    });

inputMultiplexer.addProcessor(scoreAndButton.stage);
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputMultiplexer);
```